# Read an xml file from EMS queue using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, ems

See the code below

```
public class VerifyModule extends RouteBuilder {

   public void configure() {
         from("EMS_QUEUE_ADDRESS")
            .to(localfile);
   }
}
```

1) Is this the correct way to read from an EMS queue? Please could someone give me a working example?

2) How do I instansiate and use this module in order to read from the EMS queue and populate the localfile.txt

Comment: Do you mean JMS or EMS?

Comment: I mean EMS, as in an EMS queue

Comment: Well if you go to the documentation of Camel you will see there is no component that talks to EMS. You need to build a custom component for that. http://camel.apache.org/components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this to be Tibco EMS.. if so, you need to wire up a jms component and do

ref: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html